# memory leak when printing bunch of times to a file by calling the function multiple times

Tags: c, printing, memory-leaks, printf

I keep running a memory leak when I print a bunch of times to a file by calling this function multiple times. There aren't any issues unless I actually print.

```
void print_fields_weights_energies(MKL_Complex16 *stored_fields,
                                   MKL_Complex16 *stored_energies,
                                   MKL_Complex16 *weights,
                                   int steps,
                                   int_st ist,
                                   cns_st cns) {

    /*Print The Fields Out To File*/
   int walkers;
   int fields;
   int field_number;
   double tau = steps*cns.dtau;
   char message[150];
   FILE *pf;

    /*Name and Make File*/
   sprintf(message, "fields-tau%f.dat", tau);
   pf = fopen(message, "w+");

    for (walkers=0; walkers<cns.max_number_walkers; walkers++) {
     for (fields=0; fields<ist.n_spin_orbitals_sq; fields++) {
        field_number = walkers*ist.n_spin_orbitals_sq*3+fields*3;
        fprintf(pf, "%f\t %d\t %d\t", tau, walkers, fields);
        fprintf(pf, "%f\t %f\t %f\t %f+%fi\t\t", stored_energies[walkers*3].real, stored_energies[walkers*3+1].real, stored_energies[walkers*3+2].real, weights[walkers].real, weights[walkers].imag);
        fprintf(pf, "%f\t %f+%fi\t %f+%fi\n", stored_fields[field_number].real, stored_fields[field_number+1].real, stored_fields[field_number+1].imag, stored_fields[field_number+2].real, stored_fields[field_number+2].imag);
       }
     }
    fflush(pf);
    return;
}
```

Comment: You never call `fclose`?

Comment: Sorry wrong tag. It's written in C.

Comment: Yes. I called fclose

Comment: where do you call `fclose`? the call should be in the same function where you called `fopen`, so you could close all opened files

Comment: You don’t show a call to `fclose()` in this function, and no other function can close the file opened by this function. You are consequently leaking memory and file streams and file descriptors (which are used by file streams).

Comment: I tried that. I put fclose in the same function. It doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Your secret method of memory-leak detection notwithstanding, you orphan an open file pointer, with all its internal resources (buffers, associated descriptors, etc) still attached, never to be recovered. "seeming to help" is irrelevant; it's a logical flat-out bug without the `fclose` or a clear path to process termination.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that a little bit more. I'm new to C. I'm used to writing in C++.

Comment: Same problem would occur in C++  Do you not close your files, (or let your stream instances be closed/destroyed), in your C++ apps?

Answer (score 2):

You need an fclose() at the bottom of your function (and you don't need the fflush()--the file will get flushed when it gets closed).

You also should be checking for `(pf == NULL)` before referencing it, in case of an error on the fopen().  Getting an error message is far more useful than getting a SEGV.

For future memory leaks, I highly recommend the tool "valgrind"--it tends to point you to exactly where your memory leak occurs.